# Vertical Align Two Spans (Different font size)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have been trying but cannot for the life of me make two spans with different font sizes vertically align. I have tried to use vertical-align on both the wrapper div and the spans, but to no avail.

I have considered Flexbox, but am not sure.

```css
.nav-toggle {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-toggle:hover {
    color: #d35400;
}

.triple-bar {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0 0.25em 0 0.5em;
}

.menu-text {
    line-height: 3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-toggle">
    <span class="triple-bar">&#8801;</span>
    <span class="menu-text">Menu</span>
</div>
```

Cheers, Finn!

Comment: try to use block and clear both css property for both span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align: bottom` to `.triple-bar`:

```
.triple-bar {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0 0.25em 0 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6n63umyp/)

Comment: Cool! Nice and simple. Thanks!

Comment: @FinnLeSueur You got it. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved if it answered your question?

Comment: Yep done! It said I had to wait a few minutes before I could check it off.

Comment: even the fiddle sample is still not aligned.